# Jenkins won't start

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, tomcat, 64-bit, xampp, jenkins

I'm using:

- Jenkins 1.541.
- Java JDK 7u45 (tried 64 and 32 bit versions).
- XAMPP 1.8.2

I have downloaded the default MSI installation from http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org/windows/latest, and I have installed it. Jenkins tries to run the first time, telling me *Please wait while Jenkins is getting ready to work...*

I wait but then the server, located at `http://localhost:8080/` is down. The logs don't tell much:

**jenkins.err.log**

```
nov 26, 2013 5:58:20 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
nov 26, 2013 5:58:23 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: Extract jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/jenkins.war!/ to C:\Windows\Temp\jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-jenkins.war--any-\webapp
nov 26, 2013 5:58:45 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: NO JSP Support for , did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
nov 26, 2013 5:58:46 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
nov 26, 2013 5:58:46 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Winstone Servlet Engine v2.0 running: controlPort=disabled
nov 26, 2013 5:58:46 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started initialization
nov 26, 2013 5:58:46 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Listed all plugins
nov 26, 2013 5:58:47 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Prepared all plugins
nov 26, 2013 5:58:47 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started all plugins
nov 26, 2013 5:58:47 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Augmented all extensions
nov 26, 2013 5:58:47 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Loaded all jobs
nov 26, 2013 5:58:52 PM org.jenkinsci.main.modules.sshd.SSHD start
INFO: Started SSHD at port 54677
nov 26, 2013 5:58:52 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Completed initialization
nov 26, 2013 5:58:52 PM hudson.TcpSlaveAgentListener <init>
INFO: JNLP slave agent listener started on TCP port 54678
nov 26, 2013 5:58:52 PM hudson.WebAppMain$3 run
INFO: Jenkins is fully up and running
```

After that, the server never initiates (at localhost:8080), and the Jenkins **service** is stopped.

I have also tried using **XAMPP** with **Tomcat**, trying both **32** and **64 bit Java JDK** versions to no avail, since after starting **Jenkins**, **Java** crashes. I was trying to look for a crash log but can't find any.

These are the error events from the **Event Viewer**:

```
Faulting application name: java.exe, version: 7.0.250.17, time stamp: 0x51c4b3fd
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18247, time stamp: 0x521ea8e7
Exception code: 0xc0000374
Fault offset: 0x000ce753
Faulting process id: 0x15bc
Faulting application start time: 0x01ceeaee5b2a96ab
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jre\bin\java.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
Report Id: a49749d3-56e1-11e3-b08d-00155d011200
```

And

```
Child process [5564 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jre\bin\java -Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8080] terminated with 255
```

Is there any other log I can provide to track the source problem?

Comment: I suspect this is a Java problem and not a Jenkins problem. Can you try the latest JRE (7u45)?

Comment: Hi, I'm already using the last version.

Comment: Your event viewer says you're using u25. "Faulting application name: java.exe, version: 7.0.250.17"

Comment: I suppose that's what Jenkins is using as the built in Java. I'll try with XAMPP and check the event logger.

Comment: I checked with the last version and it's the same error: `Faulting application name: java.exe, version: 7.0.450.18, time stamp: 0x525404d0`

Comment: This appears to be a bug in Jenkins. https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20630

Comment: Yes indeed. I reverted back to a previous version and it works OK now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jasonazze figured out, this is an issue with this specific version.

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20630

Downgrading fixes this bug.

Answer (score 0):

you can enable debug mode in java to get more details.... you may have to up the memory allocation available to java....

> -Xmx256m

also, as jenkins creates a huge number of files, check to make sure you didnt run out of inodes

> df -i

Comment: OP is running Windows. So inodes aren't the problem.

Comment: How can I enable debug mode for an specific Java application?

Comment: i was assuming there was a cli debug flag, but looks like its enabled via mgmt gui https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Logging

Comment: Problem is I can't access the management GUI, since jenkins can't start.

Comment: compare a backup confix.xml file you have, to the one you are running.  you can also fixup logging there, without need for gui.  in fact, jenkins works great without any gui at all :D

Comment: I have found a `jenkins.xml` file, but no `config.xml` or a backup. The arguments being sent are: `-Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8080`

Comment: Also, how can I possible fix the logging using this xml?

Comment: This seems to be a bug in 1.541. https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20630

Answer (score 0):

check the rights for c:\jenkins_node folder in windows